# calculate average with angularjs in nested json

Tags: angularjs, json

I receive a JSON response like this:

```
{
    "productDesc": "Other posterior corneal dystrophies",
    "ProductId": 1,
    "productName": "Keylex",
    "productPrice": 3529.24,
    "productStatus": false,
    "productStock": 23,
    "productModifyDate": "2016-10-13T20:13:12",
    "productUrl": "http://dummyimage.com/153x172.jpg/5fa2dd/ffffff",
    "ReviewProducts": [
      {
        "ratingReview": 8.2,
        "reviewDesc": "aaaaa",
        "ReviewProductIdNumber": 1,
        "User": {
          "username": "hsullivan0",
          "UserId": 1,
          "name": "Heather",
          "lastName": "Sullivan"
        }
      },
      {
        "ratingReview": 6.8,
        "reviewDesc": "mattis pulvinar nulla pede ullamcorper augue a suscipit nulla elit ac nulla sed",
        "ReviewProductIdNumber": 2,
        "User": {
          "username": "jcarrod",
          "UserId": 878,
          "name": "Jessica",
          "lastName": "Carr"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

What I want to do is calculate the average ratingReview from each product and show it, right now my html looks like this:

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4" ng-repeat="x in product | limitTo:30">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <img ng-src="{{x.productUrl}}" alt="">
        <div class="caption">
            <h4 class="pull-right">{{x.productPrice | currency}}</h4>
            <h4>
                <a href="#">{{x.productName}}</a>
            </h4>
            <p>{{x.productDesc}}.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="ratings" ng-repeat="review in x.ReviewProducts">
            <p class="pull-right">{{review.ratingReview}}</p>
            <p>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Actually looks like this in the browser: [image: Preview]

What I want is something like this: 
[image: Expected Result]

BTW not all products have a review rating so in case is empty show nothing

Comment: You probably want to calculate the average before you send it to the front end.  Your message from the server would come with that in a header, and then the list of products.

Comment: because you use repeat , it will repeat all review and show like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create function as below

```
$scope.getAvg= function(ReviewProducts){
    var total = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < ReviewProducts.length; i++) 
    {
       total += ReviewProducts[i].ratingReview;
    }
    var avg = total / ReviewProducts.length;
    return avg;
}
```

call this method in div as below

```
<div>{{getAvg(ReviewProducts)}}</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, can you help me with the stars? Now that I have the average how can I repeat the stars according to the average

Comment: Don't forget to check the length (don't divide by 0), see my answer.

Comment: Also try to avoid for loops, use angular.forEach instead. So you won't have weird surprises with angular arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function:

```
    <div class="ratings">
        <p class="pull-right">{{getAverage(x.ReviewProducts}}</p>
        <p>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
        </p>
    </div>
```

and:

```
$scope.getAverage = function(reviews){
    var sum = 0;
    var cpt = 0;
    angular.forEach(reviews, function(review){
        cpt++;
        sum += review.ratingReview;
    });
    if(cpt === 0){
        return 0;
    }
    return sum/cpt;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with filter like below.

```
.filter('ratingavg', function() {
    return function(data, key) {
      if (angular.isUndefined(data) || angular.isUndefined(key))
        return 0;
      var sum = 0;    
      angular.forEach(data, function(v, k) {
        sum = sum + parseInt(v[key]);
      });
      return sum / data.length;
    }

 })

<div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4" ng-repeat="x in product | limitTo:30">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <img ng-src="{{x.productUrl}}" alt="">
        <div class="caption">
            <h4 class="pull-right">{{x.productPrice | currency}}</h4>
            <h4>
                <a href="#">{{x.productName}}</a>
            </h4>
            <p>{{x.productDesc}}.</p>
        </div>
   <div class="ratings"> {{x.ReviewProducts| ratingavg:'ratingReview'}}</div>          
    </div>
</div>
```